# Populate one dropdown list based on the selection of other dropdown list and save with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, drop-down-menu

In this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/r7MN9/3/), how to save types of car and types of phones in database with php?

I mean how to save Mercedes, Volvo, BMW, porche from car and Samsung, Nokia, Iphone from phone to database?

Below is my code : 
**html**:

```
 <select id="cat">
        <option val="car">car</option>
        <option val="phone">phone</option>
    </select>

    <select id="item">

    </select>
```

**script**:

```
 cars=new Array("Mercedes","Volvo","BMW","porche");
phones=new Array('Samsung','Nokia','Iphone');

populateSelect();

$(function() {

      $('#cat').change(function(){
        populateSelect();
    });

});


function populateSelect(){
    cat=$('#cat').val();
    $('#item').html('');


    if(cat=='car'){
        cars.forEach(function(t) { 
            $('#item').append('<option>'+t+'</option>');
        });
    }

    if(cat=='phone'){
        phones.forEach(function(t) {
            $('#item').append('<option>'+t+'</option>');
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: can you post you're db structure? will they be saved on the same table?

Comment: You can use Ajax if you want :)
Here's a good example :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21313346/save-form-data-using-ajax-to-php

Comment: check out this [php+MySQL tutorial](http://w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp)

Comment: yes they will be saved on the same table, please help me